# How do I configure proxy settings from default to "auto-detect proxy settings" on Firefox (geckodriver) from selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, proxy

I'm a beginner when it comes to web-scraping with selenium and relatively new with python, but I've been trying to access a list of hotels on bing search through FireFox and I keep getting

> [the proxy server is refusing connections]

error (I'm using a rotating proxy server). I found that all I needed to do was change manual proxy configuration to auto-detect proxy settings in FireFox settings, but I cannot set it to that by default when I run selenium.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
rotating_proxy = "http://proxy_user:proxy_password@proxy_ip:80"
proxy_options = {
'proxy': {
    'http': rotating_proxy,
    'https': rotating_proxy,
    'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    }
 }
firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True

profile_path = r'C:\Users\Johann\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ull7xphc.scraper_profile'
options=Options()
options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)


profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 4)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options, seleniumwire_options=proxy_options, capabilities=firefox_capabilities)`
driver.get("https://httpbin.org/ip")
```

I tried configuring proxy settings from FireFox profile preferences, but I would just get `[firefox_profile has been deprecated, please use an Options object]` error. I also tried making a FireFox profile exclusively for scraping with my preferred proxy settings but when I try using the profile path, i don't get an error but my settings do not change. In about:profiles as well it does not say that I am using my scraper profile. How do I fix this mess?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot configure proxy password by Selenium, because Firefox don't have such an option.

The best option is to add your IP to whitelist in proxy provider.

Second option is to write simple Firefox addon which will be authorise proxy.